# finding which provider is responsible for the mail domain

Tags: node.js, dns

By provider, I mean the provider responsible for mail, e.g. for `gmail`  the provider would be `gmail`(or/by google) and for `microsoft.com` it would be `outlook`(by microsoft).

Basically, I want to find out given an email domain e.g. `abc@xyz.com`, `hxy@tuv.com` is from a specific provider(outlook or gmail) in our case, since `xyz` or `tuv` is not explicitly evident which provider it belongs to.

I have succeded somewhat, my idea being to make use of `MX` records, so I do something like this in nodejs:

```
const dnsMod = require('dns');

dnsMod.resolveMx(
    'mydomain.com', (err, value)=>{
        console.log('The error is : ', err);
        console.log('The value is : ', value);
    }
)
```

and it returns records like this:

```
[
  { exchange: 'alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 30 },
  { exchange: 'alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 10 },
  { exchange: 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 5 },
  { exchange: 'alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 20 },
  { exchange: 'alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 40 }
]
```

so, seeing this we can conclude the provider in this case is infact `gmail`.

But, my point is, is it safe to conclude the provider is gmail just it contains words like `google`, `gmail` etc. In other words, do google's mail servers always have a `google.com` in the end, (or Similarly, microsoft's mail provider have `outlook.com` or `microsoft.com` in the end)?  If not, what better way would be to confirm this?

EDIT: As per suggested by comment, I need the information because, based on the information I need to show only one of google or outlook button.

Comment: "is it safe to conclude the provider is gmail just it contains words like google, gmail" Not if it includes word (anywhere) but if it is an hostname **ending** in `.google.com` ; However all of this will still be heuristics. And people can use "vanity" names so you will see `mx1.example.com` while in reality in the backend it is another well known email provider. You may enhance your question by explaining why you need that information, because then there may be other solutions.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , by " Not if it includes word (anywhere) but if it is an hostname ending in .google.com" do you mean we can confirm it's gmail if the mail server's name ends in `.google.com`?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , also, do you mean by this: " However all of this will still be heuristics. And people can use "vanity" names so you will see mx1.example.com while in reality in the backend it is another well known email provider. " , that google can use something like :  "xyz.com" for one of their mail servers(even though it's probably not gonna happen)?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , please see the above two comments, and I've also edited the question to include what you had suggested

Comment: You can find many heuristics. For O365 for example see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/external-domain-name-system-records?view=o365-worldwide aka if there is an SPF (TXT) record with `include:spf.protection.outlook.com` you could infer that at least the sending part is handled by O365 somehow and hence "maybe" the incoming part of emails. Or "autodiscovery" through `SRV` records and specific HTTP endpoints, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: what exactly do you mean by heuristics?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , atleast please confirm this: " Not if it includes word (anywhere) but if it is an hostname ending in .google.com" do you mean we can confirm it's gmail if the mail server's name ends in .google.com?

Comment: If the `MX` hostname ends in `.google.com` it just means emails are (theoretically) managed by Google, but you can't know which "service" or even if the mail is configured correctly (anyone can put those MX records for any name, but that is not enough for email service to work).  You can then apply further heuristics when looking at things like `gmail-smtp-in` in name. But they are just heuristics. heuristic = involving or serving as an aid to learning, discovery, or problem-solving by experimental and especially trial-and-error methods. So not foolproof.

Comment: TBH, I don't understand your part " I need the information because, based on the information I need to show only one of google or outlook button." Why do you exclude people using other email services?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek , "anyone can put those MX records for any name, but that is not enough for email service to work", but, they can only put any canonical name right? The name of the mail server would have to be unique, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

For getting the information who is the responsible for the mail domain do a whois query by your prefered whois query service, pe. by https://who.is

Comment: these probably only do lookupon various records, like the dns record mentioned above. The information is probably not sufficient. Or have I missed anything? Please do point me to data that confirms me the mail service provider.

Comment: @juztcode, You should finde the adress, email adress and phone number on this way. If you dont find. Do a whois query by a other service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of eddy, you can do a whois query by automatic too:

- [Coding a domain lookup tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022057/coding-a-domain-lookup-tool/5023462#5023462)

Comment: these probably only do lookupon various records, like the dns record mentioned above. The information is probably not sufficient. Or have I missed anything? Please do point me to data that confirms me the mail service provider.

Comment: juztcode, You should finde the adress, email adress and phone number on this way. If you dont find. Do a whois query by a other service.